# Adding columns from another command by name (1st column)

Tags: bash, shell, kubectl

I have the following two commands and their outputs, for example:

```
1) kubectl top pods 

NAME                                                              CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
am-cbkc-plugin-55b9df956f-sh82g                                   3m           923Mi
amd-apigw-stack-6df456664f-sbdvc                                  3m           491Mi

2) kubectl get pods -o=custom-kubectl get pods -o=custom-columns='NAME:metadata.name,CPULIM:spec.containers[*].resources.limits.cpu,MEMLIM:spec.containers[*].resources.limits.memory'
        
NAME                                                              CPULIM   MEMLIM
am-cbkc-plugin-55b9df956f-sh82g                                   1        2Gi
amd-apigw-stack-6df456664f-sbdvc                                  550m     4Gi
```

How can I combine the columns based on the "NAME" column?

```
NAME   CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)  CPULIM   MEMLIM
....
```

Comment: Alternatively,  `awk  'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2FS$3; next} {print $0, a[FNR]}'`

Answer (score 0):

Found it by myself, it's possible by using:

```
join -j1 <(kubectl get pods -o=custom-columns='NAME:metadata.name,CPULIM:spec.containers[*].resources.limits.cpu,MEMLIM:spec.containers[*].resources.limits.memory') <(kubectl top pods) | column -t
```